# Does Doctrine2 ORM always prepare the statements? Should I always use prepared statements with DBAL?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

If I didn't get it wrong, prepared statements are faster because they are sent only the first time to the RDBMS, and then only the parameters are sent when it needs to be executed.

Should I always use prepared statements when using Doctrine2's DBAL, or only in the bottlenecks? Is there a limit to the amount of prepared statements I can have?

What about Doctrine2's ORM? Does it use normal queries by default, or prepared statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding performance, it is hardly ever the case that one script runs a query more than once. So the benefit of having a prepared statement being "faster" is nearly not existing.

The benefit of prepared statements not allowing SQL injections is also not quite correct. Prepared statements have some limitations regarding the possibilities of dynamic queries, and they are not resistant to injection per se. You can do less bad things, but not zero.

Whenever trying to optimize things: Measure. And optimize the right thing first. For example, if you have a slow query, you should first check it's execution plan and see if all indexes are used correctly. Switching from non-prepared to prepared statement will not change very much.

Comment: You mean prepared statements do not persist between requests? =s

Comment: Yes. If you'd develop a Java application, then prepared statements actually would make sense for performance as well, because handling HTTP requests is only one part of that always-running application. On the other hand, you'd introduce new problems that need answers, like db connection pooling etc.

Comment: To complete the answer, I just want to add that apparently Doctrine always uses prepared statements behind the scenes, unless you explicitly use `$conn->query($sql)` or `$conn->exec($sql)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to always use prepared (or at least parameterized) statements for all database servers, not just for speed increase, but because it helps prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: When using an ORM, the only situation with SQL injection would be if the ORM framework itself has a security problem.

Comment: Yes ok, but SQLi in Doctrine2 is prevented with both prepared and unprepared statements I think. [Example](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#fetchassoc): `$user = $conn->fetchAssoc('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?', array('jwage'));`

Comment: Well, you can always do the wrong thing and make the query string dynamic in all other parts besides where the data goes. That's where an ORM also helps because you really do not code the SQL string yourself, but create it programmatically.